# How to get the current checkout step?

Tags: onepage-checkout, javascript, onestepcheckout, ecommerce-tracking

I have a onepage checkout and need a way to get every step while clicking through the checkout. 
As the page is completly loaded I guess I can only use JavaScript.

```
checkout.accordion.currentSection;
```

That is so far my only achievment. But every time I click forward and back in my checkout there is no further response from this row. How can I achieve this with JavaScript?

Comment: This might be of help, http://inchoo.net/magento/onepage-checkout-abandonment-google-analytics/

Answer (score 4):

Try the below code, it works

In `checkout/onepage.phtml`,

To get the current section only when loads

```
 console.log(accordion.currentSection);
```

To get the current section when change section in checkout

```
 Accordion.prototype.openSection = Accordion.prototype.openSection.wrap(
    function(parentMethod, section) {
        // Call parent method
        parentMethod(section);
        console.log(accordion.currentSection);
    });
```